# MySQL: Combining the MAX method with GROUP BY Clause ERROR 1055

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table containing the monthly sales of a car-salesman who sells 3 different brands. I want to create a query which returns a table of the year, month and best selling car brand with the amount sold for that month.

A portion of the table is bellow:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+-------------+
|NYEAR| NMONTH | CAR_BRAND | AMOUNT_SOLD |
+-----+--------+-----------+-------------+
|2018    12     HONDA            15      |
|2018    12     TOYOTA           12      |
|2018    12     FORD             22      |
|2019     1     HONDA            14      |
|2019     1     TOYOTA           13      |
|2019     1     FORD             34      |
|2019     2     TOYOTA           10      |
|2019     2     FORD             19      |
|2019     2     HONDA            13      |
|2019     3     FORD             14      |
|2019     3     OYOTA            13      |
|2019     3     HONDA            15      |
|2019     4     HONDA            12      |
|2019     4     TOYOTA           14      |
|2019     4     FORD             11      |
|2019     5     FORD             11      |
|2019     5     HONDA            13      |
|2019     5     TOYOTA           10      |
+-----+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

I am able to get the answer of the Max AMOUNT_SOLD per month but can't get the stores name. Here's the query I tried.

```
SELECT NYEAR, NMONTH, MAX(SALES_AMOUNT)
FROM MONTHLY_CAR_SALES
GROUP BY NYEAR, NMONTH;
```

However when I tried to add CAR_BRAND into the select of the query:

```
SELECT NYEAR, NMONTH, CAR_BRAND, MAX(SALES_AMOUNT)
FROM MONTHLY_CAR_SALES
GROUP BY NYEAR, NMONTH;
```

I get:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'USED_CAR_SALES.MONTHLY_CAR_SALES.CAR_BRAND' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

When I try to add CAR_BRAND into the grouping clause it returns the exact same table as above, which shows every brand for every month.

The table I'm after is like this:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+-------------+
|NYEAR| NMONTH | CAR_BRAND | AMOUNT_SOLD |
+-----+--------+-----------+-------------+
|2018    12     FORD             22      |
|2019     1     FORD             34      |
|2019     2     FORD             19      |
|2019     3     HONDA            15      |
|2019     4     TOYOTA           14      |
|2019     5     HONDA            13      |
+-----+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pull out the top-selling record per month.

There are several possible approaches (notably, `not exists` and window function `row_number()`), but using a correlated subquery usually offers the better performance (and, in my opinion, readability):

```
select nyear, nmonth, car_brand, sales_amount
from monthly_car_sales cs
where sales_amount = (
    select max(sales_amount) 
    from monthly_car_sales cs1 
    where cs1.nyear = cs.nyear and cs1.nmonth = cs.nmonth
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `(nyear, nmonth, sales_amount)`.

Comment: self left join with a shifting filter to find a max per group -> `..   FROM 
     monthly_car_sales  cs
    LEFT JOIN
     monthly_car_sales  cs1
    ON
       cs1.nyear = cs.nyear and cs1.nmonth = cs.nmonth  # GROUP BY nyear,nmonth  
     AND
       cs.sales_amount < cs1.sales_amount  # MAX(sales_amount  )
    WHERE 
     cs1.sales_amount   IS NULL` i generally believes gives better performance over corelation but it might be tricky to use filtering wise also it is a bit less readable..

Comment: @GMB That's exactly what I was trying to due, thank you!

Comment: @RaymondNijland: yes I agree that’s an acceptable option too Mr NijlanD :)